# Angular Timepicker doesn't choose AM/PM or 24h clock based on locale

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, internationalization

I have my browser set to English, but I want my application to respect whatever language setting I choose there, and ignore the browser setting if they're different. It works most of the time, but I can't get it to work fully for the timepicker directive from the [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) toolset. I have one on my page, declared like this:

```
<timepicker ng-model="myThing.date" /> <!-- yes, really like this. no other attrs -->
```

It displays so:

[image: Timepicker with meridian]

Apparently it picks up the locale, because it does translate "AM" to "fm" (short for "förmiddag" in Swedish, my currently chosen language in the app). However, in Sweden we don't use the meridian time format - I want a 24h clock. I can get that by setting `show-meridian="false"` on the directive, but then I won't have an AM/PM clock when the user has set the language to English.

I've loaded `i18n/angular-locale_sv-se.js` (before loading the Angular UI Bootstrap library) as well as run `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sv');` in my ng app config, to set the locale in angular translate, but neither seem to work all the way.

How do I tell the time picker to use AM/PM or 24h clock correctly based on my chosen locale?

Comment: I think the only way you could do it would be to have an array of locales that need AM/PM and have show-meridian be true if the current locale is in that array.

Comment: @camden_kid: Sigh... If that's the case, the natural follow-up question is of course "is there a timepicker widget that can handle this natively"?

Comment: I haven't come across one. Googling "countries that use am pm" has some interesting information but sigh-inducing.

Answer (score 0):

I have similer issue with timepicker where i want to keep AM/PM as it is even i choose japanese locale in browser but convert it for all other languages.

option i found was hardcode AM/PM in angular-locale_{lang_code}.js file
but this is 3rd party angular lib which might get modified in future so we need to keep track of this change